# Using wildcards or something similar in pom files

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, appium, pom.xml

We are using Selenium in Maven Java projects. An occasional project also uses WinAppDriver.
We have a project called "Utilities" which other projects have as a dependency.  One of my projects uses both Selenium and Appium (appium for WinAppDriver).  Our current versions for Selenium are

```
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>      <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>          <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>4.11.0</version>                        <version>8.3.0</version>
```

However, Appium needs the following:

```
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>      <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>          <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>4.5.0</version>                        <version>8.1.1</version>
```

Selenium will still work with 4.5.0 and 8.1.1 but the owners want to have the latest versions.
There seems to be a bug with later versions of Appium so WinAppDriver cannot use those.
I was wondering whether there is any sort of wildcard you can use in pom files.  We are using Windows, but for the example below I will use BASH (just so you get the idea of what I want to do).

```
<version>${SELENIUM_JAVA_VERSION:-4.11.0}</version>    <version>$CLIENT_VERSION:-8.3.0}</version>
```

and then for building the project with Appium we could somehow pass SELENIUM_DATA_VERSION=4.5.0 and CLIENT_VERSION=8.1.1, and for the other projects just let the values default.

An alternative is to create another branch with the lower versions, but keeping everything consistent would be a pain.  The only difference in the two branches would be those two versions.

Another thought would be to have Jenkins do some sort of editing of the pom file before doing the build, and change the versions.  I may be able to figure that out with bash and sed, but this is Windows and I am not sure how to do that with Windows.  In this case, the easiest way would be to replace the versions with something like "*SVER*" and "*JCVER*" and then replace those in an edit, but this would require doing it for all the projects.

Any thoughts on how to do this without creating a new branch?  From what I read we need Appium so it will run on the grid.